# How to solve the system $30-4x+2x \cos(\theta) =0$ and $30 \cos(\theta) - 2x \cos (\theta) + x \cos(2 \theta) = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

I am working on a Multivariable Calculus problem and, to figure out the maxima and minima of the given function, I must solve the system of equations below:

$$
\begin{cases}
30-4x+2x \cos(\theta) &= 0\\
30 \cos(\theta) - 2x \cos (\theta) + x \cos(2 \theta) &= 0
\end{cases}
$$

I cannot figure out which substitution would provide me the result (which is $x = 10$ and $\theta = 60 ^\circ$). Can someone give me a direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Solve for $x$ in each equation and equate the two resulting expressions for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}
30-4x+2x \cos(\theta) &= 0 &(1)\\
30 \cos(\theta) - 2x \cos (\theta) + x \cos(2 \theta) &= 0&(2)
\end{cases}$$
from (1) $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{4x-30}{2x}=\frac{2x-15}{x}$$
put $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1$ into (2)so 
$$30 \cos(\theta) - 2x \cos (\theta) + x \cos(2 \theta)=0\\
30 \cos(\theta) - 2x \cos (\theta) + x (2\cos^2(\theta)-1)=0\\2x\cos^2(\theta)+30\cos(\theta)-x-2x\cos(\theta)=0 $$ now you can solve (2) for $\cos(\theta)$ or solve for $x$
for exapmle solve for x 
$$2x(\frac{2x-15}{x})^2+30(\frac{2x-15}{x})-x-2x(\frac{2x-15}{x})=0$$

Answer (score 0):

First observe that $\cos\theta\neq 1$. Then by the first equation you get $x=\frac{15}{2(1-\cos\theta)}$. Now substituting in the second equation gives $30\cos\theta-\frac{15\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}+\frac{15\cos2\theta}{2(1-\cos\theta)}=0$, whence $45\cos\theta-60\cos^2\theta+15(2\cos^2\theta-1)=0$ using $\cos 2\theta $ formula. Then you will get $(2\cos\theta-1)(\cos\theta-1)=0$. Now by the *first observation* you get the desired answer.